# How can I create a configuration entry to start server and debug Protractor tests in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, protractor

Thanks to the [ng e2e](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/e2e), I can run the server and then execute end to end Protractor tests against it. 
`npm run ng e2e` command accomplish this task for me.

Now, I would like to create a Visual Studio configuration to debug those tests.
According to the description on [MSDN blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wushuai/2016/08/24/debug-protractor-script-in-visual-studio-code/)
in `.vscode/launch.json`, I created a configuration for debugging Protractor tests:

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Launch e2e tests",
    "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor",
    "stopOnEntry": false,
    "args": ["${workspaceRoot}/protractor.conf.js"],
},
```

However it is **not** running the server, it runs the tests only.
As a results, they're marked as failed.

How can I amend the configuration to not only run the tests, but to start the server first?
Obviously I need to have debugging possibilities such as inserting the break points in VS Code.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug/issues/398

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "args": [
            "e2e"
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Works! However it writes too much information on the console during building an application (it shows progress). Is it possible to run it in silent mode?

Comment: Is the output more than if you manually execute `npm run ng e2e`?

Comment: It shows building application progress and that's is something that I want to avoid. BTW, I decided to separate building application and testing to two configurations, so that I can only restart the tests only when I commit any change in their code.

Comment: Did the building app progress show if you maually execute `npm run ng e2e` in cmd window?